# fengyuanchen Cropper - How to Fit Image into Canvas If Rotated?

Tags: javascript, crop

I gone through documentation of **cropper by fengyuanchen**.  I want the image to be fit by default into canvas if rotated. But I couldnt find a way to achieve this. Any idea how to achieve this functionality?

I want it to be like this to be default: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqJ2b.png)

Check **issue demo** here: [link](http://180.211.99.162/jt/js/issues/cropper/demo/)

Comment: Do u got any solution?

Answer (score 13):

I fixed this behavior but for my special needs. I just needed one rotate button which rotates an image in 90° steps. For other purposes you might extend/change my fix.
It works in "strict" mode by dynamically change the cropbox dimensions.

Here my function which is called, when I want to rotate an image. Ah and additionally the misplacement bug has also been fixed.

```
var $image;

function initCropper() {
$image = $('.imageUploadPreviewWrap > img').cropper({
  autoCrop : true,
  strict: true,
  background: true,
  autoCropArea: 1,
  crop: function(e) {
  }
});
}

function rotateImage() {    
    //get data
    var data = $image.cropper('getCropBoxData');
    var contData = $image.cropper('getContainerData');
    var imageData = $image.cropper('getImageData');
    //set data of cropbox to avoid unwanted behavior due to strict mode
    data.width = 2;
    data.height = 2;
    data.top = 0;
    var leftNew = (contData.width / 2) - 1;
    data.left = leftNew;
    $image.cropper('setCropBoxData',data);
    //rotate
    $image.cropper('rotate', 90);
    //get canvas data
    var canvData = $image.cropper('getCanvasData');
    //calculate new height and width based on the container dimensions
    var heightOld = canvData.height;
    var heightNew = contData.height;
    var koef = heightNew / heightOld;
    var widthNew = canvData.width * koef;
    canvData.height = heightNew;
    canvData.width = widthNew;
    canvData.top = 0;
    if (canvData.width >= contData.width) {
      canvData.left = 0;
    }
    else {
      canvData.left = (contData.width - canvData.width) / 2;
    }
    $image.cropper('setCanvasData', canvData);
    //and now set cropper "back" to full crop
    data.left = 0;
    data.top = 0;
    data.width = canvData.width;
    data.height = canvData.height;
    $image.cropper('setCropBoxData',data);
  }
```

Comment: I'd upvote this 10 times if I could - just spent hours on the exact same issue and was going round in circles until I stumbled upon this!!  Perfect solution!

Comment: Great solution. One question. Why is var koef called koef? :)

Comment: You have my deepest respect Sir/Madam. Works really nicely. Have not checked all the use cases but for now, this perfectly serves my requirement.

Comment: @ViBoNaCci most probably koef here means coefficient. As it's used for multiplying later in the code.

Answer (score 1):

This is my extended code provided by AlexanderZ to avoid cuttong wider images than container :)

```
var contData = $image.cropper('getContainerData');

$image.cropper('setCropBoxData',{
    width: 2, height: 2, top: (contData.height/ 2) - 1, left: (contData.width / 2) - 1
});

$image.cropper('rotate', 90);

var canvData = $image.cropper('getCanvasData');
var newWidth = canvData.width * (contData.height / canvData.height);

if (newWidth >= contData.width) {
    var newHeight = canvData.height * (contData.width / canvData.width);
    var newCanvData = {
        height: newHeight,
        width: contData.width,
        top: (contData.height - newHeight) / 2,
        left: 0
    };
} else {
    var newCanvData = {
        height: contData.height,
        width: newWidth,
        top: 0,
        left: (contData.width - newWidth) / 2
    };
}

$image.cropper('setCanvasData', newCanvData);
$image.cropper('setCropBoxData', newCanvData);
```

Comment: hey :) could you please explain in detail what you improved, I just don't get  it :)

Comment: Yeah, I check if width of image (canvas) is wider or not of container, if it is wider I set canvas width as container witdth and calculate height to show it in specified container. In your solution if image is wider it will be automatically cut (on left and right side of image). Of course thank you very much for that solution :)

Comment: Ahh I see, I might don't have this behavior due to css max-width to my preview image :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to the question ... but i'm betting many people that use this plugin will find this helpfull..

Made this after picking up @AlexanderZ code to rotate the image.

So ... **If you guys want to ROTATE or FLIP a image that has already a crop box defined and if you want that cropbox to rotate or flip with the image** ... use these functions:

```
function flipImage(r, data) {

    var old_cbox = $image.cropper('getCropBoxData');
    var new_cbox = $image.cropper('getCropBoxData');
    var canv     = $image.cropper('getCanvasData');

    if (data.method == "scaleX") {
        if (old_cbox.left == canv.left) {
            new_cbox.left = canv.left + canv.width - old_cbox.width;
        } else {
            new_cbox.left = 2 * canv.left + canv.width - old_cbox.left - old_cbox.width;
        }

    } else {
        new_cbox.top = canv.height - old_cbox.top - old_cbox.height;
    }

    $image.cropper('setCropBoxData', new_cbox);

    /* BUG: When rotated to a perpendicular position of the original position , the user perceived axis are now inverted. 
    Try it yourself: GO to the demo page, rotate 90 degrees then try to flip X axis, you'll notice the image flippped vertically ... but still ... it fliped in relation to its original axis*/

    if ( r == 90 || r == 270 || r == -90 || r == -270 ) {

        if ( data.method == "scaleX") {

            $image.cropper("scaleY", data.option);

        } else {

            $image.cropper("scaleX", data.option);

        }

    } else {

        $image.cropper(data.method, data.option);

    }

    $image.cropper(data.method, data.option);

}





function rotateImage(rotate) {

    /* var img = $image.cropper('getImageData'); */

    var old_cbox = $image.cropper('getCropBoxData');
    var new_cbox = $image.cropper('getCropBoxData');
    var old_canv = $image.cropper('getCanvasData');
    var old_cont = $image.cropper('getContainerData');

    $image.cropper('rotate', rotate);

    var new_canv = $image.cropper('getCanvasData');

    //calculate new height and width based on the container dimensions
    var heightOld = new_canv.height;
    var widthOld = new_canv.width;
    var heightNew = old_cont.height;
    var racio = heightNew / heightOld;
    var widthNew = new_canv.width * racio;
    new_canv.height = Math.round(heightNew);
    new_canv.width = Math.round(widthNew);
    new_canv.top = 0;

    if (new_canv.width >= old_cont.width) {
        new_canv.left = 0;
    } else {
        new_canv.left = Math.round((old_cont.width - new_canv.width) / 2);
    }

    $image.cropper('setCanvasData', new_canv);

    if (rotate == 90) {
        new_cbox.height  = racio * old_cbox.width;
        new_cbox.width   = racio * old_cbox.height;

        new_cbox.top     = new_canv.top + racio * (old_cbox.left - old_canv.left);
        new_cbox.left    = new_canv.left + racio * (old_canv.height - old_cbox.height - old_cbox.top);
    }

    new_cbox.width  = Math.round(new_cbox.width);
    new_cbox.height = Math.round(new_cbox.height);
    new_cbox.top    = Math.round(new_cbox.top);
    new_cbox.left   = Math.round(new_cbox.left);

    $image.cropper('setCropBoxData', new_cbox);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var photoToEdit = $('.photo_container img');
$( photoToEdit ).cropper({
   autoCrop : true,
   crop: function(e) {}
});
$("#rotate_left_btn").click( function () {
   $( photoToEdit ).cropper('rotate', -90);
   var containerHeightFactor = $(".photo_container").height() / $( photoToEdit).cropper('getCanvasData').height;
   if ( containerHeightFactor < 1 ) { // if canvas height is greater than the photo container height, then scale (on both x and y
      // axes to maintain aspect ratio) to make canvas height fit container height
      $( photoToEdit).cropper('scale', containerHeightFactor, containerHeightFactor);
   } else if ( $( photoToEdit).cropper('getData').scaleX != 1 || $( photoToEdit).cropper('getData').scaleY != 1 ) { // if canvas height
      // is NOT greater than container height but image is already scaled, then revert the scaling cuz the current rotation will bring
      // the image back to its original orientation (landscape/portrait)
      $( photoToEdit).cropper('scale', 1, 1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed this issue hope fully. i have added or changed the option to 0 (viewMode: 0,). Now its working well.

```
cropper = new Cropper(image, {
            dragMode: 'none',
            viewMode: 0,
            width: 400,
            height: 500,
            zoomable: true,
            rotatable: true,
            crop: function(e) {
            }
        });

document.getElementById('rotateImg').addEventListener('click', function () {
        cropper.rotate(90);
    });
```